# QMake 5.15 don't understand wildcard adding files

Tags: qt, qmake

I try to include ***.pri** file to my project (***.pro**). The PRI file looks like this

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD

FORMS += $$PWD/*.ui
HEADERS += $$PWD/*.h
SOURCES += $$PWD/*.cpp
```

And try to compile my program with MinGW compiler for Qt 5.15.2. So the compiler outputs me an error:

```
g++: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Release:131: release/*.o] Error 1
```

while the MinGW compiler for Qt 5.13.2 successfully compiles the program without any questions.

On that **line 131** in **Makefile.Release** I have

```
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o release\*.o here_my_path/src/*.cpp
```

So, what the problem is? Did the new QMake stop to support wildcards? Or it kind of a bug?

Comment: Possibly, I've found the solution - to embrace wildcards in $$files() functions like this FORMS += $$files($$PWD/*.ui)
HEADERS += $$files($$PWD/*.h)
SOURCES += $$files($$PWD/*.cpp). I think the question should be marked as solved, or removed if it is useless.

Comment: @talamaki Definitly yes.